# Exception when starting axelor-erp, web on eclipse

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate, erp, axelor

I’m running at the first time axelor-erp (web project) on eclipse. I downloaded code from github, configured PostGreSql and then started the project using gradle.
When starting, I got this exception: **Exception starting filter [guiceFilter]
org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [com.axelor.apps.base.tracking.GlobalAuditInterceptor] as strategy [org.hibernate.Interceptor]**
Any help please?

```
Exception starting filter [guiceFilter]
org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [com.axelor.apps.base.tracking.GlobalAuditInterceptor] as strategy [org.hibernate.Interceptor]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl$SessionFactoryOptionsStateStandardImpl.determineInterceptor(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl$SessionFactoryOptionsStateStandardImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:610)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService.start(JpaPersistService.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.persist.PersistFilter.init(PersistFilter.java:77)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.init(FilterDefinition.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4548)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5193)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2020-11-09 15:16:35.794 ERROR 11680 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2020-11-09 15:16:35.794 ERROR 11680 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Context [/axelor-erp] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Answer (score 0):

The back-end modules are not well configured with the project.